# Fluent NHibernate connection to MySql without MySql.Data in GAC

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

The question's title pretty much says it all.

I wanted to do so, because every time I publish or create installer from installer project, it always failed because it cannot connect to MySql.

The error says :

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not
>   be installed.

In my development PC, MySql.Data is already added to GAC so it doesn't create any problem.

Can it be done? I already set Copy Local = true.

This is my current FluentConfiguration :

```
 _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                .Database(MySQLConfiguration
                    .Standard
                    .ConnectionString(_systemSetting.ConnectionString)
                    .Provider("MySql.Data.MySqlClient")
                    .Driver<NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver>())
                .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<EmployeeMap>())
                .BuildSessionFactory();
```

Thanks.

Update : 
[image: MySql.Data.dll]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MySql.data.dll` must reside beside the assembly containing the code you posted. Also `.Provider("MySql.Data.MySqlClient")` and `.Driver<NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver>()` are redundant since you already specified `MySQLConfiguration.Standard` which already does set driver and Provider.

Comment: I have updated my question and attached a screenshot. I assumed that's where MySql.Data.dll should be located. But it's still not working.

Comment: have you removed Provider and driver from your configuration? can you somewhere register for Appdomain.AssemblyResolve and look at the information given when Mysql.data.dll or something similar is loaded?

Comment: I did, and I don't understand what you means by register Appdomain.AssemblyResolve.

Comment: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, e) => { if (e.Name.IndexOf("MySql",  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) /* Write e.Name and ((AppDomain)sender).BaseDirectory to somewhere */;  };` and compare the results to the mysql.data.dll placement and details